# Python standard libraries import best practices

Tags: python, import

Currently I am working on a Python project and I do not know what are the best practices to import standard libraries through classes.
For instance, I have `class A` and `class B`:

```
import math
import os
class A:
def x()
```

In `class B` I need to import `class A` methods and `math`. How should I

```
import math
from A import x
class B:
x()
math.pow(1, 2)
```

Or

```
from A import *
class B:
x()
math.pow(1, 2)
```

To avoid importing `math` again.

The project is written with the second version and I think it is really painful to read because I do not know where the imports come from originaly.

Comment: 1. `import` what you use, don't rely on other modules to do it for you 2. Avoid using `from foo import *` as it pollutes the global namespace

Comment: what should `from A import x` do?

Comment: Ok thank you @CoryKramer that is what I thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always avoid use

```
from math import *
```

Specially if you gonna use only a method or a class from the module. Using the * you are importing all available functions, variables and classes, which will make your application heavier and slower. Only use this option if you really will use every single submodule or you are pretty sure about what you are doing. When you use

```
from math import sqrt
```

You are saying to the Python exactly what you want to use and also improving readability of your code. This is recommended when you use no more than 3 classes/functions of a module. Now, when you use

```
import subprocess
```

You are adding a dependency to your application, but the Python will only load the necessary submodules when it finding the usages like

```
subprocess.call(...
```

You should use this when you pretend to use a lot of submodules of a module.

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect and/or misleading *"you are importing all available functions, variables and classes, which will make your application heavier and slower"* [The entire module is imported regardless](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function/187471), the `*` vs specific function just affects what ends up in the current namespace